# Find the Remainder when $100!$ is divided by $97^2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Find the Remainder when $100!$ is divided by $97^2$?

**MyApproach**

I applied Wilson Theorem here

$100$.$99$.$98$.$97$.$96!\text{ mod }97^2=100$.$99$.$98$.$96!\text{ mod }97=-970200$

I am getting wrong Ans

Can Anyone guide me how to approach the problem?

Answer (score 5):

First, compute $$a=100\cdot 99\cdot 98\pmod{97},$$ then
deduce that
$$-a=100\cdot 99\cdot 98\cdot 96!\pmod{97}$$
and that
$$-\color{red}{97}a=100!\pmod{97^{\color{red}2}}.$$

Comment: What is wrong in my approach?

Comment: Your approach says $100\cdot 99\cdot 98\cdot\color{red}{97}\cdot 96!=100\cdot 99\cdot 98\cdot 96!\pmod{97^2}$, or $97x=x\pmod{97^2}$, which is not correct. To see that, take for example $x=1$.

Comment: I edited the code

Comment: As I said above, the answer should be $97x$, not $x$. You should multiply $-970200$ by $97$ and that's the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Facts:

- $97\text{ is prime}$
- $P\text{ is prime}\iff(P-1)!+1\equiv0\pmod{P}$
- The remainder of $100!$ divided by $97^2$ is equivalent to $\frac{100!}{97}\bmod{97}$

---

Hence: $96!+1\equiv0\pmod{97}$

Hence: $96!\equiv-1\pmod{97}$

Hence: $96!\equiv96\pmod{97}$

Hence: $\frac{100!}{97}\equiv96!\cdot98\cdot99\cdot100\equiv96\cdot98\cdot99\cdot100\equiv93139200\equiv91\pmod{97}$

Comment: $100!$/$97$^$2$(97 raised to power 2)You took 1?

Comment: @justintakro: No. You asked for the remainder of the quotient of $100!$ and $97^2$, so I calculated the modulo with $97$ of the quotient of $100!$ and $97$, which is the same thing.

Comment: For the last the last calculation you can use:
$\quad$ $96\cdot98\cdot99\cdot100  \equiv -1\cdot1\cdot2\cdot3 \equiv -6 \equiv 91 \pmod{97}$

Answer (score 0):

What you did wrong is that you did not finish the calculation:

$$ -970200 = -970291 + 91 = 97\times(-10003) + 91$$

The principal remainder is therefore $91$.